# pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Reference 'title' is ambiguous, could be: title, title

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am using glue version 3.0, python version 3, spark version 3.1.
I am extracting data from xml creating dataframe and writing data to s3 path in csv format.
Before writing dataframe I printed the schema and 1 record of dataframe using show(1). till this point everything was fine.
but while writing it to csv file in s3 location got error duplicate column found as my dataframe had 2 columns namely "Title" and "title".
tried to add a new column title2 which will have content of title and thought of dropping title later with below command

> *from pyspark.sql import functions as f*
> `df=df.withcoulumn('title2',f.expr("title"))`
> but was getting error
> **Reference 'title' is ambiguous, could be: title, title**
> *Tried*
> `df=df.withcoulumn('title2',f.col("title"))`
> got same error.
> any help or approach to resolve this please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default spark is case in-sensitive, we can make spark sensitive by setting the `spark.sql.caseSensitive` to `True`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([("CaptializedTitleColumn", "title_column", ), ], ("Title", "title", ))

spark.conf.set('spark.sql.caseSensitive', True)

df.withColumn('title2',f.expr("title")) .show()
```

### Output

```
+--------------------+------------+------------+
|               Title|       title|      title2|
+--------------------+------------+------------+
|CaptializedTitleC...|title_column|title_column|
+--------------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
In AWS i set the config using below setting:
**Open Glue> Jobs > Edit Job> Script libraries and job parameters (optional) > Job parameters near the bottom
Set the following: key: --conf value: spark.sql.caseSensitive=True**